# How to create collection view like image with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: swift, collections, view, collectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

For a couple of days I can't figure out how to make a collection view like in the screenshot using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. Can anyone help ?
[Image!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHUDl.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jVirus/compositional-layouts-kit and see if you can use any of these as inspiration. Also, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1uXXVUu43o&ab_channel=LetsBuildThatApp isn't a bad tutorial for entering into UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this layout combining two vertical NSCollectionLayoutGroup in a horizontal group. Each vertical group is composed by two itens, a big and other small.

```
final class CustomLayout {



class func create() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout{
    
    //Obs: The size of each element is relative to his parent.
    //NSCollectionLayoutItem < NSCollectionLayoutGroup < NSCollectionLayoutSection < UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout
    
    
    
    //Defines the margin
    let margin: CGFloat = 5
    //Defines the space between the cells
    let contentInsests: CGFloat = 8

    
    // Create the big item that is 60% of your parent's height
    let bigItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.60)))
    
    bigItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
        top: contentInsests,
        leading: contentInsests,
        bottom: contentInsests,
        trailing: contentInsests)
    
    // Create the small item that is 40% of your parent's height
    let smallItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.40)))
    
    smallItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
        top: contentInsests,
        leading: contentInsests,
        bottom: contentInsests,
        trailing: contentInsests)
    

    //Here we Combine the two itens in a vertical group
    let group1 = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
        subitems: [bigItem,smallItem])
    
    //Here we do the same reversing the order of the itens
    let group1Reversed = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
        subitems: [smallItem, bigItem])
    
    
    //here we combine both in a nested group making the layout like in the image.
    //In this example we are making a custom layout with two "Image layout" per screen, so
   // We define his height as 0.5% of his parent's height. You can change it for your preference.
    let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5)),
        subitems: [
          group1,
        group1Reversed
        ]
    )
    
    
    //Here is our main group with two nested group
    let mainGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)),
        subitems: [
          nestedGroup,nestedGroup
        ]
    )
    
    
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: mainGroup)
    
    
    section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
        top: 0,
        leading: margin,
        bottom: 0,
        trailing: margin)
    
    let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    configuration.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    layout.configuration = configuration
    return layout
}}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rmHE.png)